# Weird Razor nesting foreach (...) { <tr> @Html.... </tr> }

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, nested

I want to do this in my Razor view:

```
@foreach (Customer cust in Model.Customers)
{
    <tr data-custid="@customer.GetIdAsText()">
        @Html.RenderPartial("CustomerListTableRow", cust)
    </tr>
}
```

As far as I understand, this should work. The foreach block contains a <tr>...</tr>. Inside that, it is in markup mode, so I need @ to switch to C# mode. The problem is that apparently the variable cust loses its type info (and value?), so it complains that it cannot cast void to object, which RenderPartial expects.

I got it working like this:

```
@foreach (Customer cust in Model.Customers)
{
    @:<tr data-custid="@customer.GetIdAsText()">
        Html.RenderPartial("CustomerListTableRow", cust);
    @:</tr>
}
```

But aside from looking puke ugly, if I let VS beautify the code, it mucks it up like this:

```
@foreach (Customer cust in Model.Customers)
{
    @:<tr data-custid="@customer.GetIdAsText()">
Html.RenderPartial("CustomerListTableRow", cust); @:</tr>                 }
```

Nice, huh? :-)

So, why doesn't the first solution work? How *should* I write it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Html.RenderPartial()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492962%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is a void method and hence it must be enclosed it with a `{ }` block:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("CustomerListTableRow", cust);}
```

What you are definitely looking for is [`Html.Partial()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402926%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), which returns an [`MvcHtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), and it can be used like this:

```
@Html.Partial("CustomerListTableRow", cust)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work,

```
@foreach (Customer cust in Model.Customers)
{
    <tr data-custid="@customer.GetIdAsText()">
        @Html.RenderPartial("CustomerListTableRow", cust);
    </tr>
}
```

Depending on the version of MVC you are running.

Can you provide more details on the error?

Comment: Look at Paolo's answer, it's the right one. I just found out myself and was going back here to answer my own question but he beat me to it. :-)